# How do I make a link list using objects in Java.

Tags: java, linked-list

This is for a assignment in class and I am having trouble with using My car objects in my link List. 
The car class has two instance variables (make, price).
How would I place the variables into the node class.

```
public class CarList {
private CarNode head = null;
private CarNode tail = null;
private int counter = 0;

public CarList() {
    head = null;
}

public int getSize() {
    return counter;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if(counter < 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
/**public CarNode firstNode() {
    return head;
}
public CarNode lastNode() {
    return tail;
}
public CarNode getNode(int target) {
    CarNode pre;
    pre = head;

    while(pre.next != null) {
        pre = pre.next;

        if(pre.data == target) {
            return pre;
        }

    }
    return null;
}**/
public void insert (String target) {
    if(head==null || target < head.data) {
        insert_at_head(target);
    return;
    }
    CarNode pre = head;

            while(pre.next != null && target > (pre.next).data) {
                pre = pre.next;

                CarNode newNode = new CarNode(target);
                newNode.next = pre.next;
                pre.next = newNode;
    }
}
}
//The CarNode Class
 class CarNode {
Car  data;
CarNode next;
CarNode  pre;

public CarNode(Car entry) {
    this.data = entry;
    next = null;
    pre  = null;
}

}

//Car Class

public class Car {
int Price;
String Make;

public Car(int pennies, String m) {
    this.Price = pennies;
    this.Make = m;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public String getMake() {
    return Make;
}

public void setPrice(int p) {
    Price = p;
}
public void setMake(String m) {
    Make = m;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i can't understand your insert method

```
public void insert (String target) {
  if(head==null || target < head.data) {
    insert_at_head(target);
  return;
  }
  CarNode pre = head;

    while(pre.next != null && target > (pre.next).data) {
        pre = pre.next;
        CarNode newNode = new CarNode(target);
        newNode.next = pre.next;
        pre.next = newNode;
   }
}
```

i think it would be:

```
public void insert (Car target) {
  if(head==null || target.compare(head.data)<0) {
    insert_at_head(target);
  }else{
     CarNode pre = head;
     while(pre.next != null && target.compare((pre.next).data)>0) {
        pre = pre.next;
        CarNode newNode = new CarNode(target);
        newNode.next = pre.next;
        pre.next = newNode;
     }
  }
}
```

and than you have to create a `int compare(Car other)` method in the Car class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "place" those variables `make` and `price` into the CarNode class, but you can use your getter and setter methods in your car class to use in your node class.

So if you are using a `Car` object in the Node class that has already been created (instantiated) then you can just use those getter and setter methods like so.

So inside the `CarNode` class, lets so we create a car and want to get that data.

```
this.data.getPrice();
```

and

```
this.data.getMake();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Java is open source you have a grate opportunity to take a look at implementation `LinkedList` that comes as part of Java Collection framework. And implement it in similar way.

Answer (score 0):

You `insert` method looks wrong to me. I believe you are trying to insert the `Car` such that linked list in ascending order. You can do this:

```
public void insert (String target) {
  counter++;
  if(head==null || target < head.data) {
    insert_at_head(target);
  }else{
     /* trying to find position such that cur is greater than target */
     CarNode pre = head, cur = head.next;
     while(cur != null && cur.data < target) {
         pre = cur;
         cur = cur.next;
     }

     /* now insert element between pre and cur */
     /* if cur is end then you might reach the end of list */
     CarNode c = new CarNode(target);
     pre.next = c;
     c.next = cur;
     if(c.next == null)
         tail = c;
  }
}
```

Comment: this won't work with my insert_at_head method 


     public void insert_at_head(Car data) {
  CarNode temp = new CarNode(data);

  temp.next = head;

  head = temp;
 }

Comment: That has been directly taken from your code. Only portion that I have changed is in `else`.